Book Request: Machshava by Topics
I am looking for a book that provides an anthology of sources on topics of machshava. Organised and that can be used as a reference book for learning a topic.

https://www.amazon.com/Daas-Torah-Source-Daniel-Eidensohn/dp/145389635X/?encoding=UTF8&pd_rd_w=zdLUa&content-id=amzn1.sym.9f654aa3-75f1-42ea-bb2c-1136f91b121f&pf_rd_p=9f654aa3-75f1-42ea-bb2c-1136f91b121f&pf_rd_r=142-8667419-8552842&pd_rd_wg=cIb5D&pd_rd_r=1d10c965-f657-4f80-9094-1adc66d67314&ref=aufs_ap_sc_dsk

This is a challenging request since most resources probably just focus on philosophies the author is aligned with. The link above and below exemplify this issue, all presenting one philosophy each and all written by controversial figures

Aspaklaria.info; R. Wiederblank

I am not 100% sure what you are looking for but A Concise Guide to Machshava by Rav Adin Steinsaltz may be a good starting point available from Amazon here

Rav Nachman of Breslov famously has a sefer called Sefer Hamiddos which whilst does indeed explore character traits, also covers a much wider gamut of machshava topics, all categorised in an easy to follow framework.
